# Cache Friendly Design of Applications

Tags: c++, performance, caching, memory-management, optimization

I've been through writing an [application](https://github.com/MagnusTiberius/iocphttpd) written in C++ and is now at the point where I have to go down into the code and make it cache-friendly.

After reading about a [presentation by Tony Albrecht](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/OO_programming/_pdf/Pitfalls_of_Object_Oriented_Programming_GCAP_09.pdf), I soon finally realized that I could do it right the first time by simply applying the principles right from design stage.

Another paper titled [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf) written by Ulrich Drepper has strong points basically telling developers like me to be aware of writing correct memory layouts in order to be cache friendly.

But then, it feels counter intuitive because:

1. Thinking in terms of memory layout in general doesn't come natural.
2. Laying out code and data in terms of sets and lines does not come natural.
3. Thinking in terms of an object having properties and actions is natural.

A good example, one which I will be facing soon as I sit down and write a custom allocator, there are two structs which are going to be handled by the allocator, shown below.

Also note that once a thread worker releases an element, the same element would have to be put into play, and so it goes on.

```
    typedef struct
    {
        OVERLAPPED Overlapped;
        WSABUF DataBuf;
        CHAR Buffer[DATA_BUFSIZE];
        byte *LPBuffer;
        vector<byte> byteBuffer;
        DWORD BytesSEND;
        DWORD BytesRECV;
    } PER_IO_OPERATION_DATA, *LPPER_IO_OPERATION_DATA;

    typedef struct
    {
        SOCKET Socket;
    } PER_HANDLE_DATA, *LPPER_HANDLE_DATA;
```

Note that WSABUF.buf and vector can be a challenge, how they will be laid out in memory. WSABUF.buf and vector buffer allocation is dynamic and it doesn't fit into a fixed size contiguous layout. I would imagine a separate allocator will have to be created for that case.

PER_HANDLE_DATA is straight forward and can easily be laid out in a contiguous fashion.

I would have to setup another struct for storing `IsActive` so that it will be laid out in one contiguous block, separate from PER_IO_OPERATION_DATA.

```
    typedef struct {
        bool isActive;
    } IODATA_STAT, *LPIODATA_STAT
```

Anyway, I'd just like to get some feedback on why do you have to be aware of the cache when starting out when it can be done after the application has been written?

Also, what's your say about reorganizing data with regards to dynamic/fixed buffer size and pointers?

Comment: Premature optimization.

Comment: Do you really have to make your code cache friendly?  Here is a nice tutorial about getting some more power on existing code without worrying about cache: https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/tutorials/492425/keep-it-hot-the-secret-to-high-performance-code

Comment: I have a strong feeling that writing your memory allocator such that it runs at O(1) (where this represents the number of allocations it is tracking) or as close to that as possible will make a much bigger difference than alignment.  i.e. A linked list style tracking system versus a fixed size unit allocation system and managing memory size / fragmentation trade offs.

Comment: "Premature Optimization" definitely fits the bill, I did more reading in that direction and found one worth posting here titled [The ‘premature optimization is evil’ myth](http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/09/06/the-premature-optimization-is-evil-myth/) and the take there is basically don't be a programmer who simply knows the language, but be an operating system engineer who can code userland applications, which means have a deep knowledge of C, C++ and perhaps assembly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Optimization

About premature optimization, I'd say it's premature if you can apply the optimization later in hindsight in response to a profiler without a series of cascading changes in your codebase. The more breathing room you have to swap out representations fairly locally and non-intrusively, the less you should worry the first time around about getting that representation optimal.

So the key thing you want to focus on getting right above all is *interface design* over implementation, especially if you're building large-scale software. A good, stable interface modeled at the appropriate level of abstraction is going to allow you to profile your code and optimize hotspots to smithereens without cascading breakages throughout your code: ideally just a few tweaks to a source file.

Productivity and maintainability are still the most valuable traits of a developer, and the vast majority of any codebase short of the lowest-level cores are going to hinge on those traits far more than your ability to achieve micro-efficient designs let alone the best possible algorithm for a task. The programming world is very saturated and competitive now and the people who can churn out maintainable applications quickly are generally the ones that win and survive to optimize another day.

And if you aren't using profilers and worried about anything more than broad algorithmic complexity, then you absolutely need a profiler first. Measure twice, optimize once. A profiler is what's going to have you making selective, discrete optimizations which is important not just to make you spend your time in a more valuable way the first time around, but to make sure you don't degrade your entire codebase into a maintenance nightmare.

### Memory Layouts

But with that caveat aside:

*1. Thinking in terms of memory layout in general doesn't come natural.*

Here I would recommend a bit of C-like thinking. It will come more naturally as you face more hotspots over your career. In your example, the variable-length struct trick becomes quite effective.

```
struct PER_IO_OPERATION_DATA
{
    ...
    byte byteBuffer[]; // size N
};
```

Simply acquire `PER_IO_OPERATION_DATA*` by using `malloc` (or your own allocator) with the size of the structure + the additional N bytes you need to make that `byteButter` side large enough. Since you're armed with C++, you can use this kind of low-level structure as an implementation detail behind a safe class conforming to RAII, applying the necessary bounds checking assertions in debug builds, with exception safety, and so forth. In C++, try to do at least that: if you need unsafe, low-level bit and byte manipulation code anywhere, make it a very private implementation detail hidden from the public interface.

That's typically the first pass for memory locality: identify the runtime-sized aggregate members of an object using the heap and fuse them into one contiguous block with the object itself.

Another useful type of generic container that's missing in the standard when you're trying to optimize for locality (as well as eliminating new/delete/malloc/free hotspots) is something like std::vector with a statically known "common case" size. Basic example:

```
struct Usually32ElementsOrLess
{
    char buf[32];
    char* ptr;
    int num_elements;
};
```

Initialize the structure to make `ptr` point to `buf` unless the number of elements exceeds the fixed size (32). In such rare cases, make `ptr` point to a heap-allocated dynamic array. Access the structure through `ptr`, not `buf`, and make sure to implement a proper copy constructor.

With C++, you can make this into a general-purpose STL-compliant container if you like with a template parameter to determine the fixed size, even variable-sized with push_backs if you introduce a member to keep track of current memory capacity in addition to size.

Having this kind of structure around, well-tested and especially in full-blown general-purpose STL form, will really help you utilize the stack more and get a bit more memory locality out of your more daily code without requiring anything more time-consuming or risky than using `std::vector`. It's suitable when most of the time, the data size has an upper bound in the common case scenarios with the heap being reserved for those rare case exceptional scenarios.

*2. Laying out code and data in terms of sets and lines does not come natural.*

Indeed, this is very unnatural to think in terms of organizing aggregates and access patterns to align and fit to a cache line. I would suggest you save such thought for only the most critical of critical hotspots.

*3. Thinking in terms of an object having properties and actions is natural.*

This doesn't get in the way of these other two things. That's public interface design, and again your ideal public interface doesn't leak these low-level optimization details into the client using that interface (unless it's just a low-level data structure used as a building block for higher-level designs).

Coming back to interface design, if you want to leave more room for efficient optimizations of representation without breaking interface designs, a strided design will help a lot. Check out the OpenGL API and how it supports all kinds of various ways of passing representations of things around. There it doesn't assume, for example, that vertex positions are stored in a separate contiguous memory block from vertex normals. Because it uses strides in the design, the vertex normals can be interleaved with the vertex positions, or they may not be. It doesn't matter and doesn't require the interface to change, so it leaves room to experiment with memory layouts without breaking anything.

In C++, you can even create like a `StrideIterator<T>(ptr, stride_size)` to make it easier to pass things around and return them in designs that could benefit from changes to the memory layout of things being passed and returned around.

### Update (Fixed Allocator)

Since you're interested in custom allocators, try this on for size:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class Pool
{
public:
    Pool(int element_size, int num_reserve)
    {
        if (sizeof(Chunk) > element_size)
            element_size = sizeof(Chunk);

        // This should use an aligned malloc.
        mem = static_cast<char*>(malloc((num_reserve+1) * element_size));

        char* ptr = static_cast<char*>(mem);
        free_chunk = reinterpret_cast<Chunk*>(ptr);
        free_chunk->next = 0;

        Chunk* last_chunk = free_chunk;
        for (int j=1; j < num_reserve+1; ++j)
        {
            ptr += element_size;
            Chunk* chunk = reinterpret_cast<Chunk*>(ptr);
            chunk->next = 0;
            last_chunk->next = chunk;
            last_chunk = chunk;
        }
    }

    ~Pool()
    {
        // This should use an aligned free.
        free(mem);
    }

    void* allocate()
    {
        assert(free_chunk && free_chunk->next && "Reserve memory exhausted!");
        Chunk* chunk = free_chunk;
        free_chunk = free_chunk->next;
        return chunk->mem;
    }

    void deallocate(void* mem)
    {
        Chunk* chunk = static_cast<Chunk*>(mem);
        chunk->next = free_chunk;
        free_chunk = chunk;
    }

    template <class T>
    T* create(const T& other)
    {
        return new(allocate()) T(other);
    }

    template <class T>
    void destroy(T* mem)
    {
        mem->~T();
        deallocate(mem);
    }

private:
    union Chunk
    {
        Chunk* next;

        // This should be max aligned.
        char mem[1];
    };
    char* mem;
    Chunk* free_chunk;
};

static double sys_time()
{
    return static_cast<double>(clock()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

int main()
{
    enum {num = 20000000};
    Pool alloc(sizeof(int), num);

    // 'Touch' the array to reduce bias in the testing.
    int** elements = new int*[num];
    for (int j=0; j < num; ++j)
        elements[j] = 0;

    for (int k=0; k < 5; ++k)
    {
        // new/delete (malloc/free)
        {
            double start_time = sys_time();
            for (int j=0; j < num; ++j)
                elements[j] = new int(j);
            for (int j=0; j < num; ++j)
                delete elements[j];
            cout << (sys_time() - start_time) << " seconds for new/delete" << endl;
        }

        // Branchless Fixed Alloc
        {
            double start_time = sys_time();
            for (int j=0; j < num; ++j)
                elements[j] = alloc.create(j);
            for (int j=0; j < num; ++j)
                alloc.destroy(elements[j]);
            cout << (sys_time() - start_time) << " seconds for branchless alloc" << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    delete[] elements;
}
```

Results on my machine:

```
1.711 seconds for new/delete
0.066 seconds for branchless alloc

1.681 seconds for new/delete
0.058 seconds for branchless alloc

1.668 seconds for new/delete
0.06 seconds for branchless alloc

1.68 seconds for new/delete
0.057 seconds for branchless alloc

1.663 seconds for new/delete
0.065 seconds for branchless alloc
```

It's a branchless pool allocator. Not safe but crazy fast. It requires you to reserve the maximum amount of memory in advance, so it's best used as a building block for an allocator which does branching and creates multiple of these reserved pools on the fly.

Comment: I finally got the [custom allocator](https://github.com/MagnusTiberius/iocphttpd/blob/master/iocphttpl/SocketIocpController.h) coded and it works pretty well for the current testing stage, though the declaration for the memory layout got started with an array of structs with a specific buffer size. I would like to iterate on this one and evolve the layout to what you were describing above, more like a Vertex Buffer declaration.

Comment: I updated the article with some code for a branchless allocator since you seem interested in those. It works in ~65 ms as opposed to new/delete which takes ~1680 ms for the same data.

Comment: I copied the code and ran it using a much lower num value of 200,000 and [here is the snapshot of the result](http://postimg.org/image/4sl9yk8e3/). It's really impressive to see numbers like that, seeing the spread as taken from my machine which has an i7 multi-core.

Comment: @benG Another thing is that that allocator, in raw form, should not be used by more than one thread at a given time. You can put some lightweight locks around it -- but given how cheap it is, the speed degrades quickly when you put locks around it. So it's best used in scenarios as local allocators to a given thread where it really counts.

Comment: If you really care about this kind of stuff and have much higher than average performance needs, I really recommend working your way backwards towards the machine, back to C and the land of bits and bytes, scraping the metal. The problem there is that you lose all the safety and structure and abstraction. And that's where C++ becomes a wonderful complement, since that's what it adds back when you wrap all that demonic code behind a type-safe, convenient C++ interface.

Comment: There is a delicate balance between expressing what the hardware can provide in the most efficient/fast way like nothing is holding it back, that is one side and other side is how high level abstractions should map to these super fast architectures. It is also a good thing you mention about how the code will be used, I was thinking about that since it came from you. I will definitely mention your name and how to reach you written down in the reference section. I need the code you wrote to get me to the next custom allocator stage, certainly learned a lot from the code.

Comment: @benG Oh cheers -- no credit is required though but much appreciated.